# Passing ul li elements using JSON to MVC 4 Controller on POST

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to wrap my head around how to pass ul li elements on Post to an MVC 4 controller. So far I understand that the ul li elements will not show up in the FormsCollection and am pretty sure that I need to pass them as a json object. So here is what I have so far based on what I could find researching ...

View Code:

```
 <ul class="listdragable" id="OperationCountries">
<lh>@Trans["OperationCountries"]</lh>

    @foreach (var item in Countries)
    { 
        if(item.Assigned == true)
        {
        <li class="country" id="@item.ID" value="@item.ID" > <input type="checkbox" name="selectedCountries" id="@item.ID" >@item.Name</li>   
        }   
    }

</ul>
<p>
    <button onclick="postSortOrder()">Click me</button>
    @*<input type="submit" value="@Trans["Save"]" /> *@
</p>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function postSortOrder() {
$.ajax({
    data: { selectedCountries: $('#OperationCountries li').get() },
    type: 'POST',
    traditional: true
    //success: updateMessage
});

}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditCountries(int id, FormCollection formCollection, List<int> selectedCountries)
```

when I check the value of selectedCountries the count is 0

I have also noticed that the FormCollection now only contains the selectedCountries object and non of my other form elements which I have not listed in the view code for simplicity. Also when I take the json approach I dont have access to the model as I do with the scaffolding.

So my question is how can I pass the UL LI items and the model of the view to the controller?

Thanks in advance for your thoughts

---

so this is what I ended up doing thanks to suggestions by Lance Hudson(Update 3 approach is what I ended up using)

I ended up taking the hidden field route

```
<input type="hidden" id="selectedCountryList" name="selectedCountryList" value="" />
<p>
    <button class="submit"  onclick="submitMyForm()">Submit</button>
</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function submitMyForm() {
    var liIds = $('#OperationCountries li').map(function (i, n) {
        return $(n).attr('id');
    }).get().join(',');

    $('#selectedCountryList').val(liIds);
    $('#myform').submit();
}

</script>
```

and my controller looks like

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditCountries(Operation operation,FormCollection     formCollection)
{
            string s = formCollection["selectedCountryList"].ToString();
            string [] selectedCountries = s.Split(',');

}
```

not sure if this is the best approach or not but it works for now. I started to dabble in how to Post complex JSON Objects and overwriting the DefaultModelBinder approaches but dont have enough understanding to take that route. I still think there should be a cleaner way of passing non input, select and textarea element values combined with the model to the action methods on the controller. Especially if your trying to do anything with JQuery UI it seems ul li elements are used extensively. Any way thanks again Lance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ajax you are posting only the li's.  I see two options, post the entire form using ajax or setup a handler so that on submit it copies the li data to a hidden.

**Update:** 
if you want to post the whole for using ajax you can do something like

```
function postSortOrder() {
    $.ajax({
        data: { 
            selectedCountries: $('#OperationCountries li').get(),
            id: $('#id')
        },
        type: 'POST'
    });
}
```

**Update 2:**
mvc can handle arrays of items also.
Model:

```
public class EditCountriesViewModel
{
    public string Note { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public Country[] Countries { get; set; }
}

public class Country
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditCountries(EditCountriesViewModel countries)
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.id);
  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.id);

  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Note);
  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Note);

  <ul>
    @for(var i = 0; i < Model.Countries.Count(); i++)
    {
      <li class="country">@Model.Countries[i].Name @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Countries[i].Selected)</li>
      @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Countries[i].Id)
    }
  </ul>
  <input type="submit" />
}
```

**Update 3:**

```
function onSubmitHandler() {
    $("#hidden_selectedCountriesString").val($('#OperationCountries li').get());
}
```

then you would need to split the result to get the numbers back into an array.

**Update 4:**
Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditCountries(int id, string name, int[] enabledCountries)
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
  @Html.Label("id");
  @Html.TextBox("id");

  @Html.Label("name");
  @Html.TextBox("name");

  <ul>
    @foreach (var country in countries)
    {
      <li class="country">@country.Value <input type="checkbox" name="enabledCountries", value = "@country.Key" /></li>
    }
  </ul>
  <input type="submit" />
}
```

Comment: if I post the entire form via ajax will the controller see the li's how would that be different from the formscollection that doesnt list the li's... and how would I go about posting the entire form via ajax

Comment: you actually post a json object that contains all the properties you want in your model.

Comment: another way is to not use ajax at all. MVC can handle collections. let me rustle up an example.

Comment: when you are looping over the collection you have to reference them like an array, so that the input names are formatted the same. Ill add an example.

Comment: I usually don't use formscollection. the model binder in mvc is pretty good. you just set one of the parameters to the model and it will populate the properties, collections are somewhat of a pain though. I have only gotten treating it like an array to work.

Comment: I have mostly also just worked with passing the model in as the scaffolding does but for this exercise I am generating ul li elements using jquery on the client and the model doesnt have access to this information

Comment: The key to the mvc version is the naming of the inputs. If mvc model binding isn't an option then I would try either of the ajax versions.

Comment: when I tried the ajax version my parameter on the controler List<int> selectedCountries is null now ... and surprisingly my formcollection lists the other items on the form but not what I am passing via AJAX ... I am also going to try the other option

Comment: I had tried something like update 4 but the problem with that is the post doesnt send checkboxes when they are not selected. I am using the checkboxes to do multi drag and drop using jquery and on submit none will be checked

Comment: ok, sounds like your back to ajax. When you try the ajax version, can you change the parameter from list<int> to int[] ? I couldn't get the List to bind.

Comment: changed the parameter type to int[] ... its still null ... what do you mean by the additional line in the ajax example: 'id: $('#id')' looking for an element with id of "id"

Comment: in that line you are creating a javascript object. the first line is your checkboxes, the second and so on would need to be the additional form data.